# Sonarqube server cannot be reached from sonarscanner - docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, sonarqube

I have sonarqube running on the aws ec2 instance. I'm using the aws codebuild to build and spin up the container in aws on the same vpc. When I try to run sonar-scanner from the project root directory, it throws the error below:

> INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.0.3.778 INFO: Java 1.8.0_121 Oracle
>   Corporation (64-bit) INFO: Linux 4.9.43-17.38.amzn1.x86_64 amd64 INFO:
>   User cache: /root/.sonar/cache ERROR: SonarQube server
>   [http://34.253.186.73:9000/sonar] can not be reached INFO:
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE INFO:
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ INFO: Total time: 5.415s INFO: Final Memory: 3M/57M INFO:
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to
>   execute SonarQube at
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:84)
>   at
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:71)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that the scanner was not able to reach the SonarQube server (failed to establish a connection).

You can try to access http://34.253.186.73:9000/sonar with your browser while debugging the problem.